# Entity Framework AddObject to only "INSERT INTO" certain columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We have a system that will use the same code to communicate with different client databases. These databases will use the same EF Model, but different connection strings.

Our problem is, not every site will be using the same **version** of our database structure; some might be missing a few columns or contain a few old columns.

If we upgrade the system to the current version, now the database model now has an extra `EmergencyContact` column. All older databases will now fail, because EF is trying to insert into this column (even though we have not set a value for this property).

Is there a way of telling EF to only use columns for which we have a value for, when it generates the INSERT INTO query?

Comment: Usually if the columns in question haven't been modified then they shouldn't be part of the `UPDATE` statement so in theory it should work. Is there a possibility they are being populated with a default value? What sort of error are you getting?

Comment: `INSERT INTO` query, not an `UPDATE`. The error says 'Invalid Column name EmergencyContact'. I assume this would come from the sql server?

Comment: Sorry completely missed that (even though it was clearly stated!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF will be fine if your schema has missing columns that are in the real database, but it will not work if you have columns in the schema that are not in the database, and there is no way to fix that.

Your only choice is to use different schemas for different databases, and write code that manages them (ie, only instantiates the version of the context you need).

Comment: that's a good point. we're currently importing a dll that contains the database model. I could just make a new schema that only includes the one table and only the columns that will be imported.

Answer (score 0):

In the case where your model does not match your database schema, EF will only insert/update the columns in the model. However, if the unknown columns are not null, EF will throw an exception. Also, if you created relational constraints on the unknown columns, of course those will not be created as they are not yet known.

Comment: Other way round. I have columns in the model that are not in the database schema.

Comment: In that case, you have to update the databases to the current model.

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't do this :(

Answer (score 0):

If the persistence layer per site is the only part that changes then I would extract your EF model into it's own version e.g.

```
DbV1.dll
DbV2.dll
```

You could then load in the appropriate DLL based on some setting from the client i.e. you could pass information as a custom header e.g.

```
db-version: 1
```

There are other more reliable ways, however, I don't know what your current setup is like so it's difficult to answer.

Comment: hmmm.. I'm interested in these more reliable ways. We have a separate web application in IIS7 set up for each version, then each client is routed to the version of the site that they are currently running. However, this is for an import API, which must be one static application for all clients. The fields are passed in the body of a POST request, which fills out the appropriate properties of a `new Member()` object. Finally, it is then `context.SaveChanges()` that throws the error. Is this enough information for you?

Comment: @ConnellWatkins Since it's a static application for all clients, you could (as part of the post) pass the version of the client and let the import API determine which context to use. That's more reliable than sending the version as a header (as headers can be tampered with).